# How to bind using kivy only?

Tags: python, user-interface, binding, widget, kivy

I want to create a Widget changing only the text of a label inside it, but all the ways I find how to change this are by changing it in the python code instead of reusing only Kivy objects.

So I have a widget like the following:

```
<AmiLabel@Label>
    color: .1, .5, .8, 1
    font_size: 16

<AmiTextInput@TextInput>
    font_size: 16

<PropertyInputForm>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        AmiLabel:
            text: 'Folder Location'
            size_hint_x: .5
        AmiTextInput:
            text: 'None'
            size_hint_x: .5

<MainFormWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        id: foo_bar
        padding: 5
        spacing: 5
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: (1, 1, 1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        orientation: 'vertical'
        AmiLabel:
            height: 36
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            text: 'Project Name'
        PropertyInputForm:
            height: 36
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            # I WANT TO CHANGE THE TEXT OF THE LABEL IN HERE
        PropertyInputForm:
            height: 36
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            # I WANT TO CHANGE THE TEXT OF THE LABEL IN HERE
```

All I want to is change the text of the label from another widget in another level without touching the python code.

¿Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way would be to add a new property to your `PropertyInputForm` and reference or set that.

```
<PropertyInputForm>:
    new_text_property: ''
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        AmiLabel:
            text: root.new_text_property
            size_hint_x: .5
        AmiTextInput:
            text: 'None'
            size_hint_x: .5
```

and later

```
       PropertyInputForm:
            height: 36
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            new_text_property: 'whatever'
```

You may also need to declare `new_text_property` in the python class to have it be a StringProperty rather than an ObjectProperty, though even that is I think not necessary in kivy 1.8.